# Can A Single Workflow Update Multiple Related Items

Tags: workflow

I have a Equipment list that includes Bldg No, Asset No, Date of Last Inspection, and Inspection Status. The list unique identifier is the Bldg No. The Bldg No may appear several times on the list, based on the number of pieces of equipment in the building. The data from several inspection forms, by way of multiple workflows, update the Date of Last Inspection. As long as there is only one Asset in a building (meaning one Bldg No line item), all workflows have been updating Date of Last Inspection as intended. My question, will the same workflow change multiple dates at the same building, where several assets are located in the building? Example: One Bldg with a furnace, elevator, hot water heater (or, 3 Assets). Will the upload of one inspection form, update the dates of all the assets, where the form is based on the Bldg No (to which the assets associated)?

Comment: The workflow logic is needed to determine what it is actually doing. If it is a SharePoint 2010 Workflow, chances are that it is only updating a single item because there are no out-of-the-box looping actions available in SharePoint 2010 Workflows, although it could be accomplished through a custom action. Please post the workflow logic if you can.

Comment: Current List = HVAC Units / List to Update = Status of Equip / Field From - Inspection Date / Update Field - Previous Inspection / Update Based on Unique Value = Bldg No. Within each Bldg may be one or more Units (represented as line items on HVAC Units List that need to be updated. Updates take place when a new inspection form is loaded. I am trying to update Previous Inspection, on HVAC Unit List, based on Bldg No, not individual equipment numbers; which I am doing now when there is only one asset at a given building. However, when multiple assets I want to use the Bldg No instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can update multiple items using a loop in sharepoint 2013 workflow this is the latest feature given in 2013 but not in SharePoint 2010 workflow

you can query the Items by Bldg No. using rest API in the workflow. You can see how to call REST API in the below link in workflow

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

You can use loop in workflow and update the list item based on condition
you can see the below screenshot for giving you awareness on the workflow loop and service call. you can also keep the conditions in loop.

Please check and let me know if you have any queries.

[image]