# How to replace he Dropdown changed value to all items in a SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, list, dropdown

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, in which I have a Dropdown choice field with choice values say 1,2,3 and 4.I have few records in the list with dropdown choice value 4.Now when I change the dropdown choice value from 4 to 5, it should reflect to all the items with value 4.I know it can be done through code, but is there any out of box feature to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no OOB option to do it, unless the column type is lookup column.

Comment: Create new list and add in source list lookup field from new list. So, when you will change value in new list it will automatically change in source list records

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a SharePoint 2013 workflow (though one could argue this is “code”).

Use the REST API to query the items with the value 4 and update them to 5.

If it were from a lookup list of values  you could trigger the workflow to run when a value in the lookup list is changed. But in this case, with a simple choice field, you would run it manually

See this previous answer for details:

[Can A Single Workflow Update Multiple Related Items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208767/can-a-single-workflow-update-multiple-related-items)

If you were using Managed Metadata, you could just change the value in the Term Store and they would be updated.